# R data.table two stage lookup

Tags: r, data.table

Example data:

```
set.seed(33)    
a = data.table(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(3,5)),
                  date = rep(seq(Sys.Date()-4, Sys.Date(), by = "day"), 2),
                  value = c(sample(seq(11,43,0.1), 5), sample(seq(201,273,0.1), 5)))
b = data.table(group = c(1, 1, 2),
                   id = c(1, 3,  5))
c = data.table(date=seq(Sys.Date()-4, Sys.Date(), by = "day"),
                   group = 1)
```

or

```
>a
    id       date value
 1:  1 2020-08-20  22.8
 2:  1 2020-08-21  12.0
 3:  1 2020-08-22  21.8
 4:  1 2020-08-23  32.6
 5:  1 2020-08-24  24.2
 6:  3 2020-08-20 242.2
 7:  3 2020-08-21 257.8
 8:  3 2020-08-22 255.0
 9:  3 2020-08-23 269.0
10:  3 2020-08-24 263.4

> b
   group id
1:     1  1
2:     1  3
3:     2  5

> c
         date group
1: 2020-08-20     1
2: 2020-08-21     1
3: 2020-08-22     1
4: 2020-08-23     1
5: 2020-08-24     1
```

I would like to join `table a` to `table b` and the temporary result to `table c`.

Another interpretation is that for each group in `table c` I would like to sum all the daily values of companies (id's) in the corresponding `table b` using the daily prices in `table a`.

**e.g.**

`table c` row 1 is group 1 on the 20th August 2020, so this corresponds to company id's 1 and 3 in `table b`, which have corresponding values of 22.8 and 242.2.

So the value for `table c` row 1 should be `22.8+242.2 = 265.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
a[, group := b[.SD, on = "id", group]]
c <- a[c, on = c("group", "date"), sum(value), by = .EACHI]
#    group       date    V1
# 1:     1 2020-08-20 272.5
# 2:     1 2020-08-21 261.1
# 3:     1 2020-08-22 312.2
# 4:     1 2020-08-23 254.0
# 5:     1 2020-08-24 227.4
```

Without modifying `a`:

```
c <- b[a, on = "id"][c, on = c("group", "date"), sum(value), by = .EACHI]
```

Updating `c` only by reference:

```
a[, group := b[.SD, on = "id", group]]
c[, V1 := a[.SD, on = c("group", "date"), sum(value), by = .EACHI]$V1]
```

Reproducible data (although not really because of the use of `Sys.Date()`):

```
set.seed(33)
a = data.table(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(3,5)),
              date = rep(seq(Sys.Date()-4, Sys.Date(), by = "day"), 2),
              value = c(sample(seq(11,43,0.1), 5), sample(seq(201,273,0.1), 5)))
b = data.table(group = c(1, 1, 2),
               id = c(1, 3,  5))
c = data.table(date=seq(Sys.Date()-4, Sys.Date(), by = "day"),
               group = 1)
```

Comment: brilliant, many thanks. I was looking to add the column to `c` yes!!

Comment: is there a way to name the column in `c` in the query?

Comment: @Laurence_jj, yes just as any regular data.table operation, replace  `sum(value)` with  `.(xyz = sum(value))`

Comment: many thanks, is it possible to modify `c` without needing to replace the whole table with the result?

Comment: @Laurence_jj updated with one such solution. Btw. two bad practices is naming (1) naming anything in R `c` name is already reserved for a function, (2) using `Sys.Date()` messes up reproducibility.